# How can I make a keyboard shortcut key to show the launcher when hidden?

Tags: 12.04, launcher, shortcut-keys, keyboard

I have the launcher hidden, I want to make a short cut key to show the launcher (pop it out).  I want to make that key the `fn` key.

1.How do I make that specific short cut key?

2.How can I make shot cut keys for different commands? e.g. show dash, etc.

Answer (score 5):

There already exist many shortcuts for similar actions.

- To show Launcher, hold the Super (aka "Windows") button for a short time.
- To show Dash, click the Super button.
- To see most useful Unity shortcuts, hold the Super button for a bit to see the shortcut window - there are many shortcut concerning working with windows, dash, HUD and other things.
- To see what shortcuts are easily available to set in Ubuntu, run your Keyboard settings application.